# Moving a Lambda function into a VPC causes it to error with `Phase: invoke Status: error Error Type: Runtime.Unknown`

Tags: .net, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have a .Net 6 Lambda function that has a *Hello World* style endpoint that is running perfectly well. It is triggered by API Gateway in proxy mode. It currently is not deployed in a VPC. However, I need to move it into the VPC so I can connect to an RDS instance running in the same VPC.

Just moving it into the VPC causes it to error with `Phase: invoke Status: error Error Type: Runtime.Unknown`.

If I research that error all I can find [this page](https://repost.aws/questions/QUj9kwp81yRlCJGzbNBuxj8Q/lambda-function-times-out-during-init-and-then-again-during-invoke-with-error-type-runtime-unknown?sc_ichannel=ha&sc_ilang=en&sc_isite=repost&sc_iplace=hp&sc_icontent=QUj9kwp81yRlCJGzbNBuxj8Q&sc_ipos=6) which lists several causes that do not seem relevant to the change I have made.

If I move it out of the VPC then works as before. **Note** it also has the same error if I put it in the default VPC.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This error code has only started popping up on Lambdas in the last month. (And Vercel and Netlify by virtue of being hosted on lambdas). Have you found any breadcrumbs / solutions yet?

Comment: We are also experiencing that. @baynezy did you find a workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem with a Python 3.11 lambda. I invoke the lambdas from a EC2 machine within the same VPC. I get the Runtime.Unknown Error almost always. It works once every ~10 functions.
I don't get any error executing the lambda outside of the VPC.

Comment: I haven't nailed it yet, but working with AWS support it is something that is failing on start-up in the application. In my case, I am having connectivity issues with SSM. I am fiddling with my Security Groups and a VPC endpoint for SSM so that I can connect.